# why super, not extends here? from the java tutorial: a short course on the basics by ray gallardo et al

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

My question is in the following code, why `Comparable<? super T>` instead of `Comparable<? extends T>` or `Comparable<T>`?

The comparable can compare `T`'s ancestors but in the list we only have `T`'s subtypes?

Also, why `T extends Object`, isn't this by default?

Write a generic method to find the maximal element in the range [begin, end) of a list.

Answer:

```java
public static <T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>> T max(List<? extends T> list, int begin, int end) {

    T maxElem = list.get(begin);

    for (++begin; begin < end; ++begin)
        if (maxElem.compareTo(list.get(begin)) < 0)
            maxElem = list.get(begin);
    return maxElem;
}
```

this is from the six edition of the Java tutorial: a short course on the basics by ray gallardo et al.

Comment: I don't think there's any reason for the `Object &` part.

Comment: In this context `super` and `extends` are opposites. `T extends Object` means that `T` is a *subtype*  of `Object` (or is `Object`). `? super T` means that `?` is a *supertype* of `T` or (typically) is `T`. Or put the other way around `T` is a subtype of `?`. If you had `Comparable<? extends T>` you had not guaranteed that every `T` can be compared to every other `T`, which you need for the method to do its work.

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly write the method signature as

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T max(List<? extends T> list, int begin, int end)
```

And that works perfectly well with most types.

But it is more strict than we need.

Consider:

```
class Aa implements Comparable<Aa> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Aa o) {
        return 0;
    }
}

class Bb extends Aa {}
```

Every instance of `Bb` knows how to compare itself with another instance of `Bb` (because a `Bb` IS-A `Aa`), but it does *not* `extend Comparable<Bb>`.

All we need is that we can compare two instances of the type, which is satisfied by checking that it or one of its parent classes implements `Comparable`.

`T extends Comparable<? super T>` requires that `T` implements `Comparable<X>` (either directly or via a superclass) where `X` is a superclass of `T`.

In our example above `class Aa implements Comparable<Object>` would also be fine.

Using `T extends Comparable<?>` doesn't work, because when we call `compareTo` all we know is that `T` can be compared to some unknown class, we don't know that it can be compared to `T`.

Comment: thanks a lot and are you saying "T extends Comparable<? super T>" makes sure that one of T's parent classes implements Comparable ?

Comment: Yes, and implements comparable for a class which `T` "is-a".

Comment: one more question, why do we need this part "T extends Object &" , say, why do we need t to extend Object?

Comment: I don’t know why they did that — I don’t think it’s needed. Perhaps an older version of Jave needed it?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is the following two things：

In `List<? extends T> list` any element is `T` or a subclass of `T`, `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>` ensure that any elements in the List implement the same parent type compar interface(If use `<T extends Comparable<? extends T>>`, there is no guarantee of this, imagine if T is Number, then `<T extends Number>` could be `Float`, `List<? extends T>` mayber `Integer`, `Float` and `Integer` have no inheritance relationship and cannot be compared directly)

`T extends Object`, Let me tell you a scene, you need to write like this, About 10 years ago, we would compile the web packaged into a war package. If there were 100 files in it, we might only modify one of the files. At this time, we would decompress the war package and compile the modified class to get it
The class file is copied separately to tomcat in the production environment.

If this is the code before modification:

```
public static <T> int method(T obj) {
    //...
}
```

Due to generic erasure, after compilation, it will become like this (note that it is only schematic, because it is bytecode after compilation, you can understand it as this):

```
public static int method(Object obj) {
    //...
}
```

Therefore, to call this method, the referenced method signature is `int method(Object)`

If you modify this method, make it bound by the interface, like this:

```
public static <T extends CharSequence> int method(T obj) {
    //...
}
```

At this time, after compilation, the method signature will become `int method(CharSequence)`

If you directly move the compiled class of this class to tomcat, then the location where it is called will report an error.

The solution is to use `<T extends Object & CharSequence>`:

```
public static <T extends Object & CharSequence> int method(T obj) {
    //...
}
```

When the generic type is erased, the type before the first & symbol will be retained, at this time, his method signature is still `int method(Object)`

Comment: sorry, i really have huge trouble understanding the broken English in your post...

Comment: @davidandcode understand, because my English is really bad and I am studying. 
Hahahahaha...